# Background and foreground in OpencV

Tags: c++, c, opencv

i'm working on a project using OpenCV243, I need to get the foreground  during a stream, my Problem is that I use the  cv::absdiff to get it doesn't really help, here is my code and the result .

```
#include <iostream>
#include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp>
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

int main (){
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    cv::Mat frame,frame1,frame2;
    cap >> frame;
    frame.copyTo(frame1);
    cv::imwrite("background.jpeg",frame1);
    int key = 0;
    while(key!=27){
        cap >> frame;
        cv::absdiff(frame, frame1, frame2);  // frame2 = frame  -frame1
        cv::imshow("foreground", frame2);
        if(key=='c'){
            //frame.copyTo(frame2);
            cv::imwrite("foreground.jpeg", frame2); 
            key = 0;
        }

        cv::imshow("frame",frame);
        key = cv::waitKey(10);
    }
    cap.release();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Background]
[image: foreground]
as you can see  the subtraction work but what I want to get is only the  values of that changed  for example if have a Pixel in the background  with   **[130,130,130]** and the same pixel has **[200,200,200]**  in the frame  I  want to get exactly the last values and not **[70,70,70]**
I've already seen this tutorial : http://mateuszstankiewicz.eu/?p=189
but I can't understand the code and I have problems setting cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 with my openCV version

thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 should work with `#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"`
The samples with OpenCV have two nice c++ examples (in the samples\cpp directory).

- bgfg_segm.cpp shows how to use the BackgroundSubtractorMOG2
- bgfg_gmg.cpp uses BackgroundSubtractorGMG

To get the last values (and asuming you meant to get the foreground pixel values) you could copy the frame using the foreground mask. This is also done in the first example, in the following snippet:

```
bg_model(img, fgmask, update_bg_model ? -1 : 0);
fgimg = Scalar::all(0);
img.copyTo(fgimg, fgmask);
```