# Video proccesing using opencv and cpp

Tags: opencv

I have written code to detect moving objects in a video by drawing contours on it. I want to remove that object and keep background as it is. Can anyone help me over this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at Background Subtraction using opencv. This can be used to achieve what you require and they are tons of tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0):

Moving objects can be easily detected by using one of the two methods:

- Frame difference [absdiff](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=absdiff#absdiff) - [Example](http://blog.cedric.ws/opencv-simple-motion-detection)
- Background/Foreground substraction [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2) - [(Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813029/999536)

Both methods result in the same binary mask where moving object is white.

Once you have a mask you can copy image using this mask like this:

```
original_image.copyTo(new_image, mask_image);
```